# Existence of a solution

Tags: calculus, integration

I have come across an equation in this paper: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0022053197923231
that I have difficulty proving.
Assume that f(x) is a log concave density function on [a,b], leading to the CDF F(x) and 1-F(x) to be log concave as well.
How can I show that this equation always has a solution x in (a,b)?

$$\int_{a}^{x} \frac{F(t)}{F(x)} dt = \int_{x}^{b} \frac{1-F(t)}{1-F(x)} dt$$
I have tried using the fact that the two continous functions on the LHS and RHS start at different values and with different slopes, and they will eventually coincide somewhere in [a,b], but I am not sure how to use the logconcavity of the functions here. I think I should be using the fact that $\frac{-F}{f}$ and $\frac{1-F}{f}$ are non increasing functions based on the definition of log concavity.

I would really appreciate any suggestions on this.Thank you!

Comment: I think you can take derivative and take log?

Comment: Are you sure you've included all the assumptions? Places where $f(x)=0$ or $f(x)=1$ seem particularly problematic.

Comment: @Hermi Thank you for your response. The derivative of the LHS is $1 - \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)^2} \int_{a}^{x} f(t) dt$ and the RHS is $ \frac{f'(x)}{(1-f(x))^2} \int_{a}^{x} \frac{1-f(t)}{1-f(x)} dt -1$, which cannot compare, but should I be taking the log of the derivaties?

Comment: @GregMartin You are right. I have modified the question, since the paper is dealing with a CDF, rather than just a function. Thanks

Comment: Is $F(X)$ a CDF on $[a,b]$ (in which case the endpoints might still be problematic)? Or is $X$ supported on a larger interval than $[a,b]$? I'd still be more specific in this post—explicitly write where $F$ is known to be positive/nonnegative, and where its one-sided limits equal $0$ and $1$.